# Wordpress - unregister widget between 17:00 hrs to 05:00 hrs using FUNCTION.PHP file

Tags: php, wordpress

My code in **function.php**

```
if ((date('H') > 17) && (date('H') < 05)) {
    $text-12 = "text-12";
    unregister_sidebar( $text-12 );
}
```

*Wordpress structure code;*

```
<div id="widget-area-2" class="site-sidebar widget-area" role="complementary">
<aside id="text-12" class="widget widget_text">
<div class="textwidget">
OFFICE IS CLOSED NOW
</div>
</aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is right but you need to use the following code or unregister

```
function my_widget_text() {
    unregister_widget( 'widget_text' );
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'my_widget_text');
```

Answer (score 1):

you mean to say the following code should i use;

```
function my_widget_text() {
    unregister_widget( 'widget_text' );
}

if ((date('H') > 17) && (date('H') < 05)) {
add_action('widgets_init', 'my_widget_text');
}
```